# Packaging Non-Python Files in a Python Library

Tags: python, packaging

I'm trying to build a Python package for [this project](https://github.com/tclancy/bluetrain/tree/master/bluetrain) that includes the .json files in /fixtures and the *.html files in /templates. When I run the packaging script based off my [setup.py](https://github.com/tclancy/bluetrain/blob/master/setup.py), it says it should include those folders in the MANIFEST it generates, but the output just says it's hard-linking them and when I try to install via pip, it dies on the following:

```
Downloading/unpacking bluetrain
  Running setup.py egg_info for package bluetrain
    error: package directory 'bluetrain/fixtures' does not exist
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info

writing pip-egg-info/bluetrain.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/bluetrain.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/bluetrain.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
error: package directory 'bluetrain/fixtures' does not exist
```

EDIT: It looks like this was an issue with legacy crud that built up in the virtualenv I was installing succeeding versions of the package into. Trying a clean virtualenv fixed the issue.

Comment: I gave up for that long time ago... Now I use .deb packages to deploy my code (just saying)

Comment: as this is still an open question I think you should answer it with your edit or vote to close it.

Comment: Done. I was going to close it but then realized it might be an aid to people as dim as I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this issue by creating a clean virtualenv and trying to build from there. It appears the constant build/ rebuild cycle in the original environment left legacy files behind that were stopping things from working as intended.